# Do you think these questions would be a good fit for the site?

Tags: discussion

The best way for the site to grow is probably by creating more original content, and also by addressing graphic design problems that people google about.

I was trying to think of questions that I would anctually enjoy answering, too, questions that would make me think creatively and come up with new information. No point in creating a bunch of adobe how-tos, we already have plenty of those.

Ok, these are some of the ones I came up with. They are not very creative, really, but it's a start.  I don't mind being the only one asking, but if you think they could work / contribute to the site, **please** feel free to grab any of these and post it.

EDIT: Taking Aarthi's fantastic feedback in consideration, edited questions and marked those already asked (in case you want to grab another one!).

---

**Hardware questions:**

- <strike>What should I consider when buying a laptop as a graphic designer?</strike>
- What are hardware / technology requirements for designers that are just starting?
- How do I calibrate my monitor to have 'real colors' / how to see 'real colors'?

---

**Being a designer**

- How do I transition from digital to print design? / How I transition from one design medium to another effectively?
- <strike>What’s the difference between an art director and a creative director?</strike>
- How can I keep up with design trends? / How do I keep my design work from looking old-fashioned or outmoded too soon?
- Can personal projects help start a career in Graphic Design?
- What are the challenges of working as a (insert specialisation) designer?

---

**Teaching design**

- How can I get my Graphic Design students more motivated?
- (New) How do I teach students modern techniques without them losing sight of fundamentals of design?

---

**Working with designers (not being one)**

(note: **Only** to be phrased in relationship with design)

- How do we go about arranging an internship for a graphic design student?
- What questions should I ask a (...) designer for a (...) position?

---

I think there are two areas we haven't really touched yet: Teaching design, and working with designers while not being one. We have lots of people coming from development, but there must people wondering about these other things too.

Are these questions you'd find appealing to answer? Some of them look quite broad, and they could be answered in other sites like workspace, but if we focus our answers in GD they could be good.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Just some quick feedback on a few of these question ideas:

> **Hardware questions:**
>
> - What type of laptop would be best for graphic designers?
> - What are hardware / technology requirements for designers that are just starting?
> - How do I calibrate my monitor to have 'real colors' / how to see 'real colors'?

For the first, this might need to be better phrased as, "What should I consider when purchasing a laptop for our new designer?" We've found that "What is the best" questions, however well-intentioned, tend to attract the wrong kind of attention and behaviors from our users. Furthermore, enough of this site's userbase is from Stack Overflow, where "best" questions are ruthlessly closed and downvoted. Just something t keep in mind.

The second might need to be phrased a little differently. The third question would be perfect, in my opinion.

> **Being a designer**
>
> - How can I start working in Print (could be anything else) design if I have no previous experience?
> - What’s the difference between an art director and a creative director?
> - How can I keep up with design trends?
> - Can personal projects help start a career in Graphic Design?
> - What are the challenges of working as a (insert specialisation) designer?

The first might need to be rephrased to, "How do I transition from digital to print design?" Or something similar. Even a slightly more genericized, "How I transition from one design medium to another effectively?" might work better.

The second question ***I*** want to know the answer to!

The third might need to be something more broad (counterintuitively) like, "How do I keep my design work from looking old-fashioned or outmoded too soon?"

The fourth is something someone like me might actually ask, to be honest. (I did some basic graphics work in college and high school, making images for friends' websites.)

The fifth might need to be reigned in slightly -- challenges could simply be "interpersonal communication yadda yadda" or it could be, "The technology for what this *needs* to be just doesn't really exist yet". That's kind of a huge range of challenges.

> **Teaching design**
>
> - How can I get my Graphic Design students more motivated?

I would also suggest, "How do I teach students modern techniques without them losing sight of fundamentals of design?" or something similar. Understanding why the hypersaturation of the 60s/70s came as a result of the the text-heavy 50s, and how we arrived at the more minimalist push in our contemporary times is important. Connecting eras of design (and their influence and responses to one another in succession) is important.

> **Working with designers (not being one)**
>
> - How do we go about arranging an internship for a graphic design student?
> - What questions should I ask a (...) designer for a (...) position?

This community would need to keep an eye on these questions to ensure they didn't turn into venting sessions about personality conflicts unrelated to design itself.

---

These were just some quick thoughts! Overall, I like what you're trying to push for, here.

Comment: 1) If you like Q2, I'll go ask it. 2) Re modern vs. fundamentals: I like the idea, but as presented it's a discussion question. The actual teaching question is answerable.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Thank you for adding Q2!

Comment: @Aarthi Great comments, thanks! The questions I imagined were just rough ideas, not finished propositions, so everything is open for editing.

Comment: @Yisela Like Aarthi, I thought it was an excellent question, and frankly I haven't asked many here and I could use some rep. ;)